# user credentials are not stored in the FireStore when signing up with Facebook

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I created a method to add user credentials to Firestore when the user sing up with Facebook

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


  void facebookSignInMethod() async {
    final LoginResult result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

    final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
        FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.accessToken!.token);

    await _auth.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential).then((user) {
      saveUser(user);
    });
```

the method is saveUser(user)

```
  void saveUser(UserCredential user) async {
    await FireStoreUser().addUserToFireStore(
      UserModel(
        userId: user.user!.uid,
        email: user.user!.email,
        name: name == null ? user.user!.displayName : name,
        pic: '',
      ),
    );
  }
```

related to the class

```
class UserModel {
  late String? userId, email, name, pic;

  UserModel({
    required this.userId,
    required this.email,
    required this.name,
    required this.pic,
  });
  UserModel.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    if (map == null) {
      return;
    }
    userId = map['userId'];
    email = map['email'];
    name = map['name'];
    pic = map['pic'];
  }
  toJson() {
    return {
      'userId': userId,
      'email': email,
      'name': name,
      'pic': pic,
    };
  }
}
```

when I register in the app using Facebook the account is added to the authentication in firebase but it's not added to the FireStore database
and this error is shown
[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiIWz.png)

Comment: Please provide all related code. The 'name' variable in saveUser function, where is it coming from? According to error, it is an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 0):

the error in this line

```
name: name == null ? user.user!.displayName : name,
```

As you are checking that if the name is null but you didn't initialize name, so you need to initialize it first before this line